# Could I have any liability for the cost of the unapproved removal a tree from my property and paid by my neighbor?

Tags: real-estate, florida

My neighbor, without my knowledge, had a tree removed from my property. The tree was diseased and would have been removed, at my expense, eventually. It was removed along with an adjacent diseased tree on the neighbor's property.

I gave the tree removal company permission to use my driveway to gain access to what I thought was only for the neighbor's tree; but was not told they were also removing the tree on my property. They may not have known.

While the work was proceeding, I didn't leave the house and could only see the trunk of the tree from my door. It wasn't until after the trunk was gone that it became apparent what they had done.

The trees were about 80 feet tall, so removing them was not a small expense.

Could I have any liability for the cost of the unapproved removal a tree from my property and paid by my neighbor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, the reverse

You could, if you wanted, sue your neighbour for the damage done to your property (the tree).